# Can we give file for translation e.g. give English file to translator/third party service for French translation

Tags: localization, translation, angular8, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate for Internationalization so how to give file for translation e.g. give English file to translator/third party service for French translation. Considering accuracy can we achieve this please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have JSON files most translators will have a CAT (computer aided translation) tool which can be used to translate JSON and it will respect the integrity of the JSON format. If the CAT tool does not filter the JSON correctly out of the box there are tweaks which can be made. If you're able to display a sample of one of your files I can provide further feedback. I'm not a translator but I 'prepare' many JSON projects for translators to work on without having to worry about breaking the file.